# Photo backpack as first carry-on luggage for travelling with Ryanair

Tags: ryanair, photography, backpacking, backpacks

I have a mirrorless camera, and I'm looking for a small photo backpack which will be fitted to Ryanair's carry-on luggage restrictions 40x20x25cm. I haven't bought a photo backpack before.

I've found Vanguard propositions and there are small but too big for Ryanair:

- https://www.vanguardworld.co.uk/collections/bags/products/veo-range-t37m-bk
- [https://www.amazon.com/VANGUARD-VEO-GO37M-BK-Mirrorless/dp/B083R4RNWD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B083R4RNWD)

I would like to carry on:

- Sony A6400 camera
- two lenses: 18-105mm and 35mm
- cards, cables, batteries
- GoPro camera (some parts GoPro equipment)
- documents and personal small items like wallet / smartphone / notepad / book

Could you suggest me some photo backpacks?

Comment: I am closing this as a size-shopping question using the price-shopping reason. Sadly this kind of questions are not fit for our site as they encourage recommendations and the gathering of information that will inevitably be incomplete - we cannot scout all bag manufacturer -, and outdated in the future - we cannot know who will release a compatible backpack and when this will happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your question is not a great fit for a Q&A website as bags come and go, there's something to be addressed here:

Ryanair restrictions -- this is a common mistake, don't fret -- are not 40 x 25 x 20.

They are 42 x 30 x 20. You can find this information at https://corporate.ryanair.com/news/new-bag-policy-from-november-will-cut-check-bag-fees-reduce-boarding-delays/ unlike the advertised limits these have no mercy at all. That's why Ryanair communicates smaller dimensions -- people will always go over it and this avoids a lot of conflict. But if you want to make an informed choice, that's the sizer.

A number of really great backpacks fit those dimensions, I posted a few to https://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/64333074

There will be a vlog about bags this size at https://smallba.gs/ stay tuned.

Comment: Thank you for briefly an explanation. So as I understand correctly, my backpack should be fitted in Ryanair's permitted bag sizer which has 42 x 30 x 20 dimensions.

Comment: Make sure you get the units right - are these inches or centimeters?

Comment: 42 inches?  A 3.5-foot (107-cm) long backpack?  I'm going to guess they mean centimeters.

Comment: Yup, centimetres!

Comment: @chx is the same story for WizzAir?

Comment: Wizzair is complicated. advertised size: 40x30x20 cm. But there's an additional "Size allowance does not include bag handles/ wheels; however, wheels must add no more than 5 cm to the size of the bag". Someone needs to measure the new sizer, the last measure we have is from 2016 and it changed in 2018. However, looking at the new sizer it looks like one edge of big bag and the small bag is the same and that only can be the 40cm one so I would not expect any leniency with the 40cm edge of the small bag... https://static2.bigstockphoto.com/1/9/3/large1500/391014347.jpg